# Adding Shopify Cart on Collection Page

Tags: jquery, shopping-cart, shopify

What I'm trying to do is add the shopping cart on each collection page. Basically I have my products listed in a span8 div and the shopping cart listed in a span4. I want the shopping cart to dynamically update as a user adds items, but at the moment, you need to refresh the page in order to see the changes take effect (not how I want it to work). In addition, when you click the remove button, it redirects you to the Shopping Cart page, instead of just removing the item on the current page and allowing the user to keep on shopping. I'm also curious, is it possible to make it so that the remove button on the actual cart page dynamically removes the item instead of reloading the page? I'm sure this can be done with an AJAX call or some jQuery but I'm not sure how to go about it.

The URL to my website: http://shoebox-delivery.myshopify.com

Answer (score 1):

Shopify provides an Ajax-Json API that allows you to work with products and the cart.

The document is at https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api

Comment: I've seen the documentation but it isn't helping me a whole lot. I'm having trouble integrating it for a dynamic cart .. I've tried playing around with the documentation for CartJS as well and still no luck.

Comment: Take a look at Shopify Timber framework http://shopify.github.io/Timber/#ajax-cart and their github repo https://github.com/Shopify/Timber